# How to add test-package to available sources in Play?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have several mock-classes in my test-folder of my Play Java project ([see anatomy here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Anatomy)).

I have also prefixed all classes in the *app*- and *test*-folders with my domain, however that is allowed in Play 2 and works fine. My structure is now like this:

```
app
 └ my.domain
   └ conf
   └ controllers
   └ models
   └ views
build.sbt
conf
 └ application.conf
 └ routes             → controller-package for routes definitions adapted to my.domain
test
 └ my.domain
   └ mock             → I want to use sources/classes in here in my app!
```

**My problem is:** I want to reference classes in *test/my.domain.mock* in my GlobalSettings in my *app*-folder. But if I do that, Play says `cannot find symbol`.

I managed to get rid of errors within IntelliJ Idea simply by adding the test-folder to the sources of my app in the module-settings, but I don't know how to do this so that Play recognizes it too. I guess I would have to alter my build.sbt file, I just have now clue how. I'd appreciate any advice!

**EDIT**

By request, this is my current GlobalSettings-class:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    private final Injector INJECTOR = createInjector();

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application application) {
        super.onStart(application);
    }

    @Override
    public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> controllerClass) throws Exception {
        return INJECTOR.getInstance(controllerClass);
    }

    private static Injector createInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {

            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(UrlGenerator.class).to(ProductiveUrlGenerator.class).in(Singleton.class);
                // this is the problem: since I have another MockGlobal (manually inserted as a fake-application parameter) in my test-folder, I don't really need the mocked classes here
                // but for this service in particular, I want to make sure that it's not even used in dev-mode, only productive, but as long as my MockService is in the test-folder I can't access it here
                bind(ImportantService.class).to(Play.isProd() ? ProductiveService.class : MockService.class).in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Like I commented in the code, the `MockService.class` is in *test/my.domain.mock* and therefore I can't access it in my GlobalSettings in the app-folder. I do have another `MockGlobal`-class binding all the other mock-classes in my test-folder for test-runs, and of course within the same folder there's access to my mock-classes, so until now that was fine. I then used the mocked global like this in my tests:

```
fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase(), mockGlobalInstance)
```

I just tried moving the whole mock-package in my test-folder to the app-folder, leaving only the tests in the test-folder but not the mock-classes. That seems to work like you said, I just thought it would be cleaner to keep them separate from my productive classes in the app-folder.

PS: I'm using Guice not only for tests, but also for staying flexible regarding which services are used (easy switching of modules).

Comment: This is intended this way. The normal app classpath has no access to the test classpath. It's actually strange that you want to do this. If you need a class at normal app runtime, just move it to the app folder.

Comment: Hm.. ok I just started with Play, so if that's strange maybe I just misunderstood the anatomy. Should I just move my mock-classes (e.g. I'm mocking some services for tests that I inject with Guice) to my app-folder? That would solve it I guess, I just thought it's cleaner if those classes are in the test-folder.

Comment: Maybe you can show why you need in your GlobalSettings. Maybe you don't even need Guice. Show a little bit more and we can maybe figure it out :-)

Comment: Ok I edited, hope it's not too confusing. Maybe I'm completely on the wrong track anyway. ;)

Comment: @mavilein Nevermind, I gave up my strange plan of adding additional sources and just moved the classes I need at runtime to my app-folder like you suggested. I also changed how I differentiate between productive and testing Guice-modules in only one GlobalSettings-class, and actually this looks even cleaner than before. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your hint. If you want you can write a nice answer with explanations and I'll accept. ;)

Comment: Great that you got a cleaner solution now. I read your updated post and couldn't come up with a good answer anyway.

Comment: Tried to come up with a proper summary as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is intended this way. A Play project (or any Scala/Java project) has one classpath for normal runtime of your application and one for your tests.

**The normal runtime classpath** contains all classes that are needed to start the application. In Play this classpath consists of the classes in your app folder and your library dependencies.

```
// example for a library dependency that you can add to your classpath in build.sbt in the project directory
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s" % "1.0.1.1"
)
```

**The test classpath** contains all classes that are needed to test your application. The normal runtime classpath has no access to the test classpath. The test classpath has access to the normal runtime classpath, because it needs access to those classes so you can test your application, right? Additionally the test classpath consists of the classes in your test folder and the library dependecies that are scoped with test, e.g.:

```
// import the mockito libray that you only use in testing
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5" % "test"
)
```

**Conclusion:**
It's actually strange that you want to do this. If you need a class at normal app runtime, just move it to the app folder. It makes not much sense to use a test class at normal runtime. **If you want to use it at normal runtime, it is not a test class :-)**

Comment: Makes perfect sense :)